# Is it still possible to install nuxt app with nuxt CLI with preconfigured custom server framework?

Tags: nuxt.js

I am watching a nuxt.js course that shows nuxt.js CLI giving an option to "Use a custom server framework". However when I run the `npx create-nuxt-app` no such option is given during installation config.

Has this server preconfiguration been permanently removed from the nuxt.js? Is it possible to still achieve this somehow?

As shown here (paid course): https://www.udemy.com/course/nuxtjs-vuejs-on-steroids/learn/lecture/9175088#questions

Comment: Can you show us the course? Would be faster to find out what is the author using.

Comment: It's Academind's course 'Nuxt.js - Vue.js on Steroids' https://www.udemy.com/course/nuxtjs-vuejs-on-steroids/ from Udemy, so unfortunately not publicly accessible.

Comment: Hopefully, I already bought this one. Could you link the specific course and the timestamp?

Comment: Here's direct link to the lecture: https://www.udemy.com/course/nuxtjs-vuejs-on-steroids/learn/lecture/9175088#questions. He starts the installation around 0:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, I remember this one yeah! (nostalgy)

As said by Pooya in this github issue: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/563#issuecomment-656611288
This feature was removed from the CLI because it introduced several possible issues for newcomers.
The recommended way is to simply use Express.js. And it should behave pretty much alike in a lot of those backends either way IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use Express.js, but when I saw this setup via CLI I hoped that preconfigured example will make it much simpler to figure out how to combine them. There are some preconfigs mentioned in the comment you linked. I'll have a look at them. Again thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks! May I ask you a side question, as you seem knowledgeable in the nuxt ecosystem? I want to build a nuxt app to exercise what I learned in the course, but I also want to learn GraphQL at the same time and connect to my mongoDB database. Would you be able to recommend a hosting with a free or cheap plan that would fit this combination of technologies?

Comment: @Eggon thanks for the kind words. <3 I've starting working with GraphQL few months ago thanks to Hasura and their great quick course: https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/vue/introduction/ Their service was super nice (for the few times I've used it) and it can totally plug itself on MongoDB!

Comment: thanks a lot! You're awesome! :) I'll give it a try then. May the Force be with you! :)